# Opening Adobe illustrator CS5 file in CorelDRAW X5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, corel-draw

I was totally new to graphic design and the best I could do was resize images in MS Paint or use Word 2010. Than I discovered Adobe Illustartor as I needed to make a logo and Letter Head. After breaking my head against my monitor (does not hurt any more) and learning it for 2 weeks, I became sufficiently good enough (if I can be excused to say that) and designed the logo and letterhead. Now it has to go to print.

The problem is that all the commercial printers and the people who use them, HERE use CorelDRAW and not only that but also older versions from 9 to 15. They refuse to take Adobe Illustrator files or even CorelDRAW files above version 12 such as v15 or X5. They refuse to work with PDF files also. No Word 2010 files either. Simply and Only CorelDRAW files of version 9 to 12.

The Adobe Illustrator CS5 does not have options of saving the files in ".cdr" format. And when I import or open the ".ai" file in CorelDRAW X5, many things happen. Color changes of text as well as objects. Some objects do not get displayed. Alignment and positioning gets changed, and many others.

I have taken some steps after reading on the net to make it easier for CorelDRAW X5 to import the ".ai" files. And also tried many things. These include, but are not limited to..

1. Uncheck/disable the "compression" when saving the file in AI-CS5.
2. Uncheck/disable the "Embed ICC Prile" when saving in AI-CS5.
3. Convert all text to outlines.
4. Saving in "SVG", "PDF" all different versions.
5. Saving in older AI-CS5 Legacy versions.
6. Exporting the file from AI-CS5 in different file formats.
7. Importing the file from CD-X5.
8. Working in RGB Color Mode.

... And many more.

Please note that I can not be expected to fresh learn CD-X5 and abandon AI-CS5 and design from the begining, if that is a "sole" answer. Also my design is simple enough. Attached are 2 pics. One of the logo and the other of the letterhead. Just 3 rounded rectangles filled with 2 color gradients and vectors of animals with styles applied to those animals and with text at the bottom. (can't post images, need 10+ rep for that)

**The Logo**
http://oi44.tinypic.com/ieqs0m.jpg
[image: logo]

**The LetterHead**
http://oi41.tinypic.com/1zzj03s.jpg
[image: letterhead]

Please further note (yes! I know, you have heard that many times) that although I was successful in designing (the asthetic beauty of the design is another matter), I am still new to designing. So Color Theroy or Font theroy have not made past me. And I wonder what's the point of having a standard of "SVG" If these so called "Vector Editing Applications" can not handle the files uniformly?

I guess my question is how to either

1. Export/Save/Save As/Place the file from AI-CS5 to CD-X5
2. Import/Open/Open As/Place the file in CS-X5 from AI-CS5

Without changes being made to it. My objective to to hand over a print ready file to the printing guys.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A) Find better printers. B) What about simply saving as PDF. They do accept PDFs don't they?

Comment: @Scott : I am afraid I can't find "better printers" as there are none. And as stated by me they dont accept PDF's. Only and Only CorelDRAW from version 9 to version 12.

Comment: Can it be done by either (1) saving it as EPS in AI-CS5, (2) Printing it in "postscript" in AI-CS5. I don't know these terms and dont understnd them.

Comment: Wow. Never have I come across a print provder which demands only old CorelDraw files. They may as well state "We don't want your business" Honestly, there are online printers galore which will accept PDFs and do fabulous jobs printing them.

Comment: @Scott : I read that CD-X5 came a month earlier than AI-CS5. Do you think they would have added this capability bug free by updates. I see that CD-X5 has Hot Fix 4 and Service Pack 3.

Comment: I can't really say. I'm not a Corel user and never have been. In 25+ years in the business I have never found a print provider which demands ONLY Corel files.

Comment: The competing software will rarely be on-par with Adobe products in terms of version compatibility. Often those files have to be reverse engineered and that takes a huge amount of effort.

Comment: @Scott, I have encountered this (albeit with signwriters not printers). Additionally, I assume Jawad is in Pakistan, where the print industry may differ from your experience.

Comment: Got it working by Saving the file in Adobe Illustartor CS5 as PDF Version 4 and opening the same in CorelDRAW Graphic Suite X6. Pixel Perfect (Not that I can use this term for Vector) file with no messups. Although I have no idea why it works. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: @e100 : Got it working by Saving the file in Adobe Illustartor CS5 as PDF Version 4 and opening the same in CorelDRAW Graphic Suite X6. Pixel Perfect (Not that I can use this term for Vector) file with no messups. Although I have no idea why it works. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems you describe have been issues with Corel for years. I've run into it working with small specialty engraving shops that have equipment that only understands Corel files so they *have* to import to Corel.

Your best *vector* option at this point is to export an RGB version as an EPS (not .AI) in AI8 format. If that can import correctly into X5, you'll be okay, but I have to warn you that I've seen problems even from those legacy formats. Otherwise, you're left with exporting a high resolution TIFF for import into Corel, or learning Corel.

Not the best news, I'm afraid, but those are your best options.

Comment: I'd be tempted to render TIFFs sooner, and maybe ask the printer if they can use those. I've done this (usually separating CMYK too) where for whatever reason PDFs have had issues.

Comment: Got it working by Saving the file in Adobe Illustartor CS5 as PDF Version 4 and opening the same in CorelDRAW Graphic Suite X6. Pixel Perfect (Not that I can use this term for Vector) file with no messups. Although I have no idea why it works. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

While I still advocate going local whenever you can when it comes to printing--as it's nice to have a good relationship with one--it's also rather trivial to send your jobs out to print nearly anywhere on the planet now with the internet. I'd spend a bit of time online and find a printer that can handle your files.

Adobe, alas, is the standard in this industry and any printer not supporting standard Adobe product files is likely not a printer you want to deal with for a whole number of reasons.

If you have no other choice but to go with local printers, that leaves you with two options:

1. In AI, do a SAVE AS and save it back to the oldest format you can for an AI file. It's rare for competing software to be able to open native Adobe files that are current or even one or 2 versions back.
2. Barring that, learn Corel Draw. I know you don't like that answer, but you may be surprised with it not being as difficult as you think. By learning AI, you've learned 80% of the concepts that nearly every vector based drawing tool uses.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help me. Before I go ahead and start learning CD-X5 I would like to try out all other options. Let me try and exhaust all other possibilities and turn to learning CS-X5 as a last resort. Thanks again.

Comment: Got it working by Saving the file in Adobe Illustartor CS5 as PDF Version 4 and opening the same in CorelDRAW Graphic Suite X6. Pixel Perfect (Not that I can use this term for Vector) file with no messups. Although I have no idea why it works. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Arts & Letters?
For years I used A&L, and the eps files it made were so simple, both Corel and Adobe could open the eps directly, and the color was the true color I designed.

Although I have switched to Adobe, because I had to work on Newsletters and PDF files, I may however re-install A&L; and A&L is a true Vector program.

Website is: https://www.arts-letters.com/

nailbreak